# custom post type tags

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, tags

I have this code:

```
$args=array(
        'post_type' => array ('portfolio'),
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies
      );
        if($pf_categorynotin){
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $pf_categorynotin,
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                )
            ); //category__in
        }
```

What I'm asking is how to add also "portfolio_tag" taxonomy because I want to list tags from my custom post type. 
Any suggestions on how to achieve this ? 
Thanks!

Later edit: here is  snippet of the code that is used to retrieve portfolio categories and how they are displayed: 
[snippet](http://pastebin.com/6tAAiSa7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this function to display comma separated terms from a custom taxonomy:

```
// Get Comma Seperated List of Custom Taxonomy //
function the_custom_taxonomies($taxonomy) {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
    $counter = 0;
    if (!empty($terms)) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo $term->name;
            if (++$counter < count($terms))
                echo ", ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But where is the taxonomy variable defined? And I don't think it will work in my case because the theme I use loads content through AJAX

Comment: You should be able to just get away with `implode( ',', $terms )` instead of looping.

Comment: Just call it like this: `the_custom_taxonomies( 'my_taxonomy' )`.

Comment: I've just updated my post with a snippet of the code, please take a look.